# How to display scrollbar's arrows only, instead of full the scrollbar

Tags: html, css

It may sound stupid, but I'm curious about this, is there any trick to display the scrollbar's arrows only instead of displaying full of the scrollbar?

Like this one: https://prnt.sc/1u29xpr

Comment: Try searching for a good carousel

Comment: You can use icons with javascript to translate the position

Comment: See [scrollbar CSS from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) or try a [scrollbar tutorial/blog](https://orangeable.com/css/scrollbars)